# How can I load data into a variable through a click function that matches data fields in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to toggle series of questions on and off depending on the answer a user selects.  So far  this is what I've come up with

```
activator(ans){
     this.Toggler = {value: ans.trigger};
     this.SubData = this.Data.micros.find(activate => activate == this.Toggler.value);
 }
```

So far the `.find()` method is the only thing I seen that seems to be built for what I want to do but when I click on an answer nothing happens.  After looking at it closer I'm not even sure if I'm telling it to grab the data. Here's what my component looks like so far.

`question-shell.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit,
         OnChanges, Input,
         Output, EventEmitter }         from '@angular/core';

import { QuestionPrimative, 
         Answer, QuestionBase,
         MicroQuestions, Question }     from '../../data-types';



@Component ({
    moduleId    : module.id,
    selector    : 'question-shell',
    templateUrl : './question-shell.component.html'
})

export class QuestionShell implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() Data: Question;
    @Output() Trigger: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    Toggler = {value: ''};
    SubData: MicroQuestions;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(){
        //console.log(this.Data);
        //console.log(this.Toggler);
    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        //this.activator()
        //console.log(this.SubData);
    }

    activator(ans){
        this.Toggler = {value: ans.trigger};
        this.SubData = this.Data.micros.find(activate => activate == this.Toggler.value);
    }
}
```

`question-shell.component.html`

```
<!-- SMALL TEXT INPUT -->
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'sm_input'">
    <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <label class="center-block">
            {{Data.question}}:
            <input class="form-control"
                [attr.id]="Data.id"
                [attr.name]="Data.name"
            >
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</ng-container>

<!-- LARGE TEXT INPUT -->
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'lg_input'">
    <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <label class="center-block">
            {{Data.question}}
            <textarea
                [attr.id]="Data.id"
                [attr.name]="Data.name"
            ></textarea>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</ng-container>

<!-- DROP DOWN INPUT -->
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'drop_input'">
    <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <label class="center-block">
            {{Data.question}}
            <select class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let ans of Data.answers ">
                    {{ans.answer}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</ng-container>

<!-- MULTIPLE CHOICE INPUT -->
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'multi_choice'">
    <fieldset class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" style="background-color:#777;">
            <label class="col-xs-11 col-sm-7">
                {{Data.question}}
            </label>


            <label *ngFor="let ans of Data.answers" [attr.for]="ans.id" class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="radio" 
                    [attr.id]="ans.id"
                    [attr.value]="ans.answer"
                    [attr.name]="Data.name"
                >
                {{ans.answer}}
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-4"></div>
    </fieldset>
</ng-container>

<!-- MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH NESTED QUESTIONS -->
<ng-container *ngIf="Data.template == 'multi_choice_nested'">
    <fieldset class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" style="background-color:#777;">
            <label class="col-xs-11 col-sm-7">
                {{Data.question}}
            </label>


            <label *ngFor="let ans of Data.answers" [attr.for]="ans.id" class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="radio" 
                    [attr.id]="ans.id"
                    [attr.value]="ans.answer"
                    [attr.name]="Data.name"
                    (click)="activator(ans)"
                >
                {{ans.answer}}
            </label>
            {{Toggler | json}}
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-4"></div>
    </fieldset>

    <ng-container *ngIf="Toggler.value">
        <p>hi</p>
        <question-shell *ngFor="let a of SubData?.questions" [Data]="a"></question-shell>
    </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

The way I have my data organized is like this

```
//This gets passed into the Data variable of the component class through an @Input()
{
    "question": "blahblah",   // loads where I want the question to display
    "id"      : "blahblah",   // the id attribute
    "name"    : "blahblah",   // the name attribute
    "formctrl": "blahblah",   // for AngularForms when I get to it
    "template": "blablah",    // to match ngIf of appropriate chunk of HTML
    "answers" : {....},       // all available answers if multiple choice
    "micros"  : {....}        // groups of questions that toggle based on answer
},
{
    //another question
}



//The answers are shaped like this
{
    "answer" : "blahblah",
    "id"     : "blahblah",
    "trigger": "blahblah"    // to be used logically to trigger data in micros field
},
{
    //next answer
}



//The micros object is shaped like this
{
    "activate": "blahblah",  //what the trigger in the question matches with
    "questions": {...}       //series of questions to load if match is made
},
{
    //next micro section
}
```

Here's what an actual chunk of data looks like that the function will work on

```
{
        "formctrl"  : "website",
        "id"        : "bus_exp_02",
        "name"      : "bus_info_02",
        "question"  : "Do you have a website?",
        "answers"   : [
            {"answer" : "yes",  "id" : "bus_info_02_a_01_01",   "trigger" : "yes"},
            {"answer" : "no",   "id" : "bus_info_02_a_01_02",   "trigger" : "no"}
        ],
        "template"  : "multi_choice_nested",
        "micros"    : [
            {
                "activate"  : "yes",
                "questions" : [
                    {
                        "formctrl"  : "web_link",
                        "id"        : "web_yes_01",
                        "question"  : "Website",
                        "template"  : "sm_input"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "activate"  : "no",
                "questions" : [
                    {
                        "formctrl"  : "industry",
                        "id"        : "web_no_01",
                        "name"      : "web_no_q_01",
                        "question"  : "What type of Industry do you operate in?",
                        "template"  : "sm_input"
                    },
                    {
                        "formctrl"  : "products",
                        "id"        : "web_no_02",
                        "name"      : "web_no_q_02",
                        "question"  : "What specialty products and or services stand at the forefront of who you are to your Customers?",
                        "template"  : "sm_input"
                    },
                    {
                        "formctrl"  : "contentness",
                        "id"        : "web_no_03",
                        "name"      : "web_no_q_03",
                        "question"  : "Would you rather be known for something else despite your current success?",
                        "template"  : "sm_input"
                    },
                    {
                        "formctrl"  : "logo",
                        "id"        : "web_no_04",
                        "name"      : "web_no_q_04",
                        "question"  : "Do you already have a logo?",
                        "answers"   :[
                            {"answer" : "yes",  "id" : "web_no_04_a_01",    "trigger" : "yes"},
                            {"answer" : "no",   "id" : "web_no_04_a_02",    "trigger" : "no"}
                        ],
                        "template"  : "multi_choice_nested",
                        "micros"    : [
                            {
                                "activate"  : "yes",
                                "questions" : [
                                    {
                                        "formctrl"  : "logo_picture",
                                        "id"        : "web_no_04_micro_01",
                                        "name"      : "web_no_q_04_micro_q_01",
                                        "question"  : "If you have a picture please upload below.",
                                        "template"  : "upload_input"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "formctrl"  : "brand_changes",
                                        "id"        : "web_now_04_micro_02",
                                        "name"      : "web_no_q_04_micro_q_2",
                                        "question"  : "What type of change are you seeking to undergo?",
                                        "answers"   : [
                                            {
                                                "answer": "Bringing my Brand up to date.",
                                                "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_01"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "answer": "Mild facelift and minor changes",
                                                "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_02"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "answer": "Re-invent the look of my Brand with the same symbols and messages.",
                                                "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_03"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "answer": "Start fresh with clean slate and new everything.",
                                                "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_04"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "template" : "multi_choice"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

here's the rest of my JSON data if needed

```
{
    "basic_info"    : [
        {
            "formctrl"  : "name",
            "id"        : "name_input",
            "question"  : "Name",
            "template"  : "sm_input"
        },
        {
            "formctrl"  : "phone",
            "id"        : "phone_input",
            "question"  : "Phone",
            "template"  : "sm_input"
        },
        {
            "formctrl"  : "email",
            "id"        : "email_input",
            "question"  : "Email",
            "template"  : "sm_input"
        },
        {
            "formctrl"  : "business_name",
            "id"        : "business_name_input",
            "question"  : "Business Name",
            "template"  : "sm_input"
        },
        {
            "formctrl"  : "city",
            "id"        : "city_input",
            "question"  : "City",
            "template"  : "sm_input"
        },
        {
            "formctrl"  : "state",
            "id"        : "state_input",
            "question"  : "State",
            "template"  : "drop_input",
            "answers"   : [
                {"answer" : "Alabama"},     {"answer" : "Alaska"},          {"answer" : "Arizona"},
                {"answer" : "Arkansas"},    {"answer" : "California"},      {"answer" : "Colorado"},
                {"answer" : "Connecticut"}, {"answer" : "Delaware"},        {"answer" : "Florida"},
                {"answer" : "Georgia"},     {"answer" : "Hawaii"},          {"answer" : "Idaho"},
                {"answer" : "Illinois"},    {"answer" : "Indiana"},         {"answer" : "Iowa"},
                {"answer" : "Kansas"},      {"answer" : "Kentucky"},        {"answer" : "Louisiana"},
                {"answer" : "Maine"},       {"answer" : "Maryland"},        {"answer" : "Massachusetts"},
                {"answer" : "Michigan"},    {"answer" : "Minnesota"},       {"answer" : "Mississippi"},
                {"answer" : "Missouri"},    {"answer" : "Montana"},         {"answer" : "Nebraska"},
                {"answer" : "Nevada"},      {"answer" : "New Hampshire"},   {"answer" : "New Jersey"},
                {"answer" : "New Mexico"},  {"answer" : "New York"},        {"answer" : "North Carolina"},
                {"answer" : "North Dakota"},{"answer" : "Ohio"},            {"answer" : "Oklahoma"},
                {"answer" : "Oregon"},      {"answer" : "Pennsylvania"},    {"answer" : "Rhode Island"},
                {"answer" : "South Carolina"},{"answer" : "South Dakota"},  {"answer" : "Tennessee"},
                {"answer" : "Texas"},       {"answer" : "Vermont"},         {"answer" : "Vermont"},
                {"answer" : "Virginia"},    {"answer" : "Washington"},      {"answer" : "West Virginia"},
                {"answer" : "Wisconsin"},   {"answer" : "Wyoming"}
            ]
        }

    ],
    "business_info" : [
        {
            "formctrl"  : "business_experirence",
            "id"        : "bus_exp_01",
            "name"      : "bus_info_01",
            "question"  : "How long have you been in Business?",
            "answers"   : [
                {"answer" : "Less than 4 months",   "id" : "bus_info_01_a_01"},
                {"answer" : "4 months - 7 months",  "id" : "bus_info_01_a_02"},
                {"answer" : "7 months - 1 year",    "id" : "bus_info_01_a_03"},
                {"answer" : "1-2 years",            "id" : "bus_info_01_a_04"},
                {"answer" : "2-5 years",            "id" : "bus_info_01_a_05"},
                {"answer" : "5-10 years",           "id" : "bus_info_01_a_06"},
                {"answer" : "10+ years",            "id" : "bus_info_01_a_07"}
            ],
            "template"  : "multi_choice"
        },
        {
            "formctrl"  : "website",
            "id"        : "bus_exp_02",
            "name"      : "bus_info_02",
            "question"  : "Do you have a website?",
            "answers"   : [
                {"answer" : "yes",  "id" : "bus_info_02_a_01_01",   "trigger" : "yes"},
                {"answer" : "no",   "id" : "bus_info_02_a_01_02",   "trigger" : "no"}
            ],
            "template"  : "multi_choice_nested",
            "micros"    : [
                {
                    "activate"  : "yes",
                    "questions" : [
                        {
                            "formctrl"  : "web_link",
                            "id"        : "web_yes_01",
                            "question"  : "Website",
                            "template"  : "sm_input"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "activate"  : "no",
                    "questions" : [
                        {
                            "formctrl"  : "industry",
                            "id"        : "web_no_01",
                            "name"      : "web_no_q_01",
                            "question"  : "What type of Industry do you operate in?",
                            "template"  : "sm_input"
                        },
                        {
                            "formctrl"  : "products",
                            "id"        : "web_no_02",
                            "name"      : "web_no_q_02",
                            "question"  : "What specialty products and or services stand at the forefront of who you are to your Customers?",
                            "template"  : "sm_input"
                        },
                        {
                            "formctrl"  : "contentness",
                            "id"        : "web_no_03",
                            "name"      : "web_no_q_03",
                            "question"  : "Would you rather be known for something else despite your current success?",
                            "template"  : "sm_input"
                        },
                        {
                            "formctrl"  : "logo",
                            "id"        : "web_no_04",
                            "name"      : "web_no_q_04",
                            "question"  : "Do you already have a logo?",
                            "answers"   :[
                                {"answer" : "yes",  "id" : "web_no_04_a_01",    "trigger" : "yes"},
                                {"answer" : "no",   "id" : "web_no_04_a_02",    "trigger" : "no"}
                            ],
                            "template"  : "multi_choice_nested",
                            "micros"    : [
                                {
                                    "activate"  : "yes",
                                    "questions" : [
                                        {
                                            "formctrl"  : "logo_picture",
                                            "id"        : "web_no_04_micro_01",
                                            "name"      : "web_no_q_04_micro_q_01",
                                            "question"  : "If you have a picture please upload below.",
                                            "template"  : "upload_input"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "formctrl"  : "brand_changes",
                                            "id"        : "web_now_04_micro_02",
                                            "name"      : "web_no_q_04_micro_q_2",
                                            "question"  : "What type of change are you seeking to undergo?",
                                            "answers"   : [
                                                {
                                                    "answer": "Bringing my Brand up to date.",
                                                    "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_01"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "answer": "Mild facelift and minor changes",
                                                    "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_02"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "answer": "Re-invent the look of my Brand with the same symbols and messages.",
                                                    "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_03"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "answer": "Start fresh with clean slate and new everything.",
                                                    "id"    : "web_no_04_micro_02_a_04"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "template" : "multi_choice"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish here is when the user clicks an answer, the `trigger: '...'` value in the answer will be matched to the `activate: '...'` field in the `micros` objects and return that object to the `SubData` variable.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so after speed reading/studying ES6 and Javascript docs I came up with this and it works perfectly.

```
activator(ans){
    let switcher = ans.trigger;
    let data = this.Data.micros;
    this.Toggler = switcher;
    this.SubData = data.find(a => a.activate == switcher);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is way too long, I suggest you break it down to small questions.

about the activator function, your signature look wrong:

```
activator(ans, _data: Data.value.micros)
```

ans with no type and _data of type of another prop?
when you call this method from the DOM, you pass only one param,
this is why _data is undefined and this is the cause the error your are facing.

Comment: I just updated it, I was trying to give more background for what I was trying to achieve and why to help reduce the amount of time people might waste coming up with answers that don't suit the bigger picture of what I'm going for which inevitably leads to more poking around, tweaking, researching, etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly micros is an object and not an array, this is why find won't work. I don't see what micros looks like, please provide a json example for micros that you want to iterate on.

Comment: ok I just updated the question again.  I decided to get rid of `Firebase` and just go with a JSON file so everything is different now, except for the fact it still doesn't work lol.